# VBA Macro - Identify the duplicate rows and specifics rows

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

Sample data with expected result [image]

```
Sub HighlightDuplicateRows()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet ' Change this to the appropriate worksheet
    
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' Change "A" to the column where the data starts
    
    Dim firstNames As Object
    Set firstNames = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim lastNames As Object
    Set lastNames = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim uniqueIDs As Object
    Set uniqueIDs = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To lastRow ' Assuming headers are in row 1
        Dim firstName As String
        firstName = ws.Cells(i, "A").Value ' Change "A" to the appropriate column for first name
        
        Dim lastName As String
        lastName = ws.Cells(i, "B").Value ' Change "B" to the appropriate column for last name
        
        Dim uniqueID As String
        uniqueID = ws.Cells(i, "C").Value ' Change "C" to the appropriate column for unique ID
        
        If firstNames.Exists(firstName) And lastNames.Exists(lastName) And uniqueIDs.Exists(uniqueID) Then
            ' Highlight the original row
            Dim origRow As Variant
            origRow = Application.Match(firstName & lastName & uniqueID, _
                ws.Range("A2:C" & i - 1), 0)
            If IsNumeric(origRow) Then
                ws.Rows(origRow).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) ' Highlight the row yellow
            End If
            
            ' Highlight the current row
            ws.Rows(i).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) ' Highlight the row yellow
        Else
            firstNames(firstName) = True
            lastNames(lastName) = True
            uniqueIDs(uniqueID) = True
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

i tried to highlight the duplicates rows and specific rows
Rule 1 : if First, last name and Unique id repeated more than once im highlighting the row
Rule 2:  if First, last name repeated more than once and unique id contains STATEWIDE im highlighting the row  its not selecting the correct rows

can anyone help?

Comment: "im not getting 100% accuracy" is not very helpful. Please be specific.

Comment: its not selecting correct rows

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to do this is not with VBA at all.

1. Sort the list on State, Lastname, Firstname, and UniqueID
2. Enter two conditional formatting formulas on the entire table range

   a. First one - `=OR($E2=$E1,$E2=$E3)`  Format background as Yellow

   b. Second one - `=OR(AND($A2=$A1,$B2=$B1,$D2=$D1),AND($A2=$A3,$B2=$B3,$D2=$D3))` Format background as Orange

It is important to not have dollar sign anchors in front of the numbers

Finally, if for some reason you still want it in VBA, you should still follow this algorithm:  sort the whole table in VBA, then make conditional formulas on the entire table.  Warning, conditional formulas are somewhat tricky in VBA; the data structures are complicated.

Comment: Yeah its working as expected thanks for your suggestion